# My service account is not able to access BigQuery Data even if it have sufficient permission

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to query data in BigQuery by using BigQuery API.
These are what I've done.

1. Create service account from "API Services" menu
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC9Tm.png)
2. I gave "BigQuery Data Editor" and "BigQuery User" permission to it
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHW1b.png)
3. Added key to this service account
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfPBH.png)
4. Try to retrieve data from BigQuery table on that project with the service account I made. But it fails with the error message below.

> Access Denied: Table [project ID]-[table name]: User does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table [project ID]-[table name].

This is very weird because on [BigQuery predefined IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions) in Google document, "bigquery.tables.get" permission is included in "BigQuery Data Editor".
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFifu.png)

I double checked that the service account have "BigQuery Data Editor" and "BigQuery User" permission from IAM & Admin menu. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EF61.png)
I try this process many times to confirm that I don't make a mistake, but the result won't changed. What can be the reason for this problem? Any comment will be appreciated.

p.s. I use Software named DataBricks, data analytics tool provided by microsoft, by following [this step](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/google/bigquery.html). FIrst I doubted the configuration on DataBricks, But as I succeeded to retrieve the data with another BigQuery account, I think the problem exist on this BigQuery account.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you're not running with the credentials you think?  Can you run a query from your databricks tool to verify?  Something like `SELECT SESSION_USER() as whoami` should confirm things.

The other most likely thing that could cause this error is that the tool is trying to use a different project ID than you're expecting.  Does databricks have a configuration option for defining the default project ID to use?

Comment: Thanks for the comments shollyman. I'm looking for the command to execute that kind of query on DataBricks, but still not able to find it. Let me update once I find it. DataBricks have a configuration option for defining the default project ID and I explicitly defined the project ID, but it won't work. Again, I appreciate your comment.

Comment: I tried the command you provided and confirmed the query was run by the service account I intended to use.
Now I'm assuming VPC network on GCP is restricting access from databricks.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc?hl=en

Comment: Yes, if there's VPC-SC policy involved, it could be a likely source of issues.